ID Token in MSAL User Token Cache Is Missing Custom Claims Present In Token from AcquireInteractiveToken
I am using PublicClientApplicationBuilder to add Microsoft Azure AD B2C to a desktop application. We are extending an existing Identity Experience Framework custom policy already in use for a website so users can also use the desktop application.
The process works, allowing users to login to B2C using AcquireTokenInteractive.
Part of my requirements is to allow for silent token refreshing and allow users to use the desktop application even when internet is not available, as users are expected to take their laptop into the field.
I have setup a token cache (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Cross-platform-Token-Cache), but the application is for Windows only, so I am only providing the required parameters
// cache file name is a random .txt file name
// CacheDir is set to a test directory within %ProgramData%
var storageProperties = new StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder(_cacheFileName, CacheDir).Build();

I followed this guidance (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/acquire-token-silently) and am attempting to use AcquireTokenSilent to check for a good a valid token and/or refresh the token. I followed this guidance (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-token-lifetime) to setup the custom policy with the default token lifetime values.
After an initial interactive login, the token is cached, but the cached token's IdToken string is hundreds of characters shorter than the one retrieved by the interactive login. When the token is decoded using JWT Decode, the expected custom claims are missing.
Our B2C process enriched our user tokens with defined "extension_" claims before it is returned to the calling application/website. The enrichment is defined within the custom policy as an API call.
I do not understand why the cached token doesn't contain any of our custom claims. The custom claims come through fine during the interactive process.
I am calling the exact same scopes for both AcquireTokenInteractive and AcquireTokenSilent:
public readonly string[] ScopeList = { $"openid", "offline_access" };

Followed Microsoft and git examples to establish MSAL token cache and use PublicClientApplicationBuilder's AcquireTokenSilent method to attempt to refresh user tokens and allow users to access the desktop application when offline.
The token from AcquireTokenSilent is missing all of the enriched claims provided by our B2C policy.

UPDATE: I've found the answer. Turns out it was a problem with the B2C custom policy. The RedeemRefreshToken user journey was pointing to the default in the base file. I added a new user journey in my extensions file and made sure it included my API call orchestration step.

I've found the answer. Turns out it was a problem with the B2C custom policy. The RedeemRefreshToken user journey was pointing to the default in the base file. I added a new user journey in my extensions file and made sure it included my API call orchestration step.
